# Renaming columns after dataframe names

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I am still a newbee in R. I have 24 csv files. I would like to import them (at once without having to call them one by one) as dataframes with shorter dataframe names and, for each dataframe replace some colnames based on the name of the dataframe (or the .csv file name). Here follows an example with 3 dataframes.

```
df_ABX <- read.table(text = 'Name   col1    col2    col3    col4
                             name1  10  20  30  40
                             name2   5  10  15  20
                             name13 17  16  15  14', 
                 header = TRUE)  

df_BAX <- read.table(text = 'Name   col1    col2    col3    col4
                             name1  11  21  31  41
                             name2   4   9   8  19
                             name13 10  10  15  15', 
                 header = TRUE)

df_XAB <- read.table(text = 'Name   col1    col2    col3    col4
                             name1   9  19  29  28
                             name2  15  15  55  25
                             name13 18  10  11  12', 
                 header = TRUE)
```

In the previous example, I would like the csv file named `myverylongtitle_df_ABX.csv`, `myverylongtitle_df_ABX.csv` and `myverylongtitle_df_ABX.csv` to be imported as dataframe with following names: `df_ABX`, `df_ABX`, `df_ABX`. Then, I would like `col1`, `col2`, `col3` to be renamed `A`, `B` or `X` depending on the position of these letters in the dataframe name. For example: `col2` should be renamed after the letter in position 2 in dataframe names, that is: `B` if dataframe is `df_ABX`, `A` if dataframe is `df_BAX`, and `Z` if dataframe is `df_XAB`. Same should apply for `col1` (position 1) and `col3` (position 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rename_at` after placing it in a `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(df_ABX, df_BAX, df_XAB) %>% 
      imap(~  {
      nm1 <- str_remove(.y, 'df_') %>%
               strsplit("") %>% 
               unlist
   .x %>%
         rename_at(2:4, ~ nm1)})
#$df_ABX
#    Name  A  B  X col4
#1  name1 10 20 30   40
#2  name2  5 10 15   20
#3 name13 17 16 15   14

#$df_BAX
#    Name  B  A  X col4
#1  name1 11 21 31   41
#2  name2  4  9  8   19
#3 name13 10 10 15   15

#$df_XAB
#    Name  X  A  B col4
#1  name1  9 19 29   28
#2  name2 15 15 55   25
#3 name13 18 10 11   12
```

Comment: This works perfectly (for the second part of my request) and `list2env(mylist,.GlobalEnv)` enables me to convert the list of dataframes into separate dataframe in the global environment. What if I want to obtain the same list of dataframes but with same column order for all dataframes?

Comment: @Elixterra Glad to know it works, but I would keep it in a list instead of having separate dataset updated in the global space because at the end you may again need to do some loop to write the data into files

Comment: @Elixterra  Also, it might be good to read it into a list first, `lst1 <- map(files, readr::read_csv)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with a list, this is a way to do it:

```
files <- c("myverylongtitle_df_ABX.csv","myverylongtitle_df_BAX.csv","myverylongtitle_df_BXA.csv")

lapply(files,function(file)
  {
  df <- read.table(file)
  spl <- strsplit(file,"_")[[1]]
  name <- sub("\\.csv","",spl[length(spl)])
  names(df)[2:4] <- strsplit(name,"")[[1]])
  return(paste0("df_",name)=df)
})
```